# how to Resizing these Scalling arrows in maya

Tags: maya

[image]

Please any one help me that how to resize these arrows because these are to small i am feeling uncomfortable in working

Comment: This question isn't a good fit for stack overflow, as this has nothing to do with programming. SO isnt a general help desk answered anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the size of your manipulator with the <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> keys